# Apostrophe CMS - Protecting Static Content

Tags: node.js, express, apostrophe-cms

I am working with apostrophe cms right now and have put the entire application behind a SAML IDP using Apostrophe-Saml. however, I have noticed that files that users upload, are placed into a 'public' directory and can be viewed without logging in. Is there a way that uploaded images/videos/files can be secured behind authentication?

The apostrophe-express module has a middleware option, but this does not appear to be used when accessing static content.

My next attempt was to override an apostrophe-assets method

```
self.servePublicAssets = function() {
  var middleware = [];
  if (self.lessMiddleware) {
    // bc: only if the new implementation of enableLessMiddleware is in place.
    // If it's an old override, it'll already be added to Express and
    // this property won't be set
    middleware.push(self.lessMiddleware);
  }


  //THIS NEXT LINE IS THE LINE OF INTEREST
  middleware.push(self.apos.express.static(self.apos.rootDir + '/public'));
  //SEE THE LINE ABOVE


  self.expressMiddleware = {
    // Run really early, before all of the stuff apostrophe-express normally
    // puts in, for performance reasons. Preempts expensive
    // queries related to `apostrophe-global` on every static file
    when: 'beforeRequired',
    middleware: middleware
  };
};
```

I essentially tried to swap the 'line of interest' out for something that looks like this:

```
middleware.push(self.apos.app.use(self.apos.rootDir + '/public', authMethod(), self.apos.express.static(self.apos.rootDir + '/public')));
```

But this did not appear to work either. Does anyone have any ideas or know exactly how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: You're going in the right general direction but this feature doesn't exist in Apostrophe yet. I've updated the ticket that tracks it for you with the latest, which is that since attachments now keep an array of the `docIds` in which they appear, it is potentially possible to do what you want, checking Apostrophe permissions correctly based on those documents:

https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe/issues/853

Although in your case I think you just want to restrict it to "you're logged in" and not any more strictly than that. 

Is your `authMethod` being invoked at all?

Comment: Thanks for the response Tom. The  authMethod is seemingly NOT invoked. The change mentioned above, just times out and gives a heap overflow error. Any thoughts? I will take a look at the issue you mentioned

Comment: Honestly not sure why this happens. We may implement this for an in-house client with a need at some point, or it may be something that waits for an enterprise client to support the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

While difficult at the time the question was asked, this is now straightforward: install and configure the [apostrophe-secure-attachments](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apostrophe-secure-attachments) module.